# Android ImageView PostInvalidate not working all the time

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, okhttp

I have extended an ImageView in Android where I download an image, and when the image arrives I invalidate the view to get a redraw. If I use caching it's not working all the time, so I suspect that android is ignoring some invalidate commands if the system has just already repaint. Without cache it's slower and I get the drawing working, with cache it's faster and from time to time not all imageview get redrawn. (in the flow I get a first onDraw call by the framework, and when my image is ready I call postInvalidate and I get a second onDraw where I draw the bitmap on the canvas)

```
@Override
    public void onLoadImage(Bitmap image, State state) {

        _image = image;
        postInvalidate();


    }

 @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {


        if (_image == null) {
            super.onDraw(canvas);
        } else {

            Rect destination = new Rect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

            canvas.drawBitmap(_image, null, destination, _paint);
        }

    }
```

the okHttpClient is configured like that (below), the onLoadImage take place in the onResponse callback from the networking library so not in the UI thread that's why I use postInvalidate instead of Invalidate

```
private static volatile OkHttpClient _httpClient = null;

    public static OkHttpClient getHttpClient() {

        if(_httpClient == null)
        {
            synchronized (Factory.class) {
                if (_httpClient == null) _httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().retryOnConnectionFailure(true).cache(getHttpCache()).build();
            }
        }
        return _httpClient;
    }
```

Does android ignore Invalidate on some occasions? any help would be welcome!
Thx